# Deploying apps to Google Cloud without local machine

Tags: git, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Just set up my BitBucket repository to sync with my Google Cloud app. It seems that to deploy the Google Cloud app I need to execute commands from my local machine - which I obviously do not need as the initial repository is remote, I don't even need it on my local machine.

Is there a way to build the the app right from Google Cloud or even make this process automated on each git push?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We use for that purpose a service called Codeship.
https://codeship.com/

You can connect your Git Repository (Github, BitBucket,...) and run tests and deployment on every git push. Even to Google AppEngine. We do that every day.

EDIT
Or you could use Google Cloud deployment Pipelines -> [Doc](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.co.at/2014/09/using-bitbucket-for-push-to-deploy.html)

Comment: Thank you! But isn't it possible just to build an app from source code on Google Cloud? Sounds like nonsense to me...

Comment: Ok, you just to build and deploy. Yes there is a way to do that using Google Cloud deployment pipelines see -> http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.co.at/2014/09/using-bitbucket-for-push-to-deploy.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you definitely can. But there needs to be some code present in your virtual machine. For a very simple deployment you can use a bash script which does the following:

- Installs any prior dependencies git/node etc
- Pulls your code from your repo (authentication can be managed via SSH keys)
- Puts this code to a designated folder and installs the init service for that project
- If rest is configured properly (endpoints, firewall etc), then your code should be up and running.

For the process of configuration and checking wether the code you are deploying is passing all the test, most people tend to use a continuos integration system. As @Bruno mentioned Codeship is one of them or you can find other open source and freely available ones.

Deploying untested code to a server is not a great idea, but hey, it is possible.